how to use pandas to compute rolling cumulative distinct count over past 24 hrs?
I have a transaction data with three columns including user_account, transaction_id and transaction_date respectively. I'd like to compute rolling cumulative counts of distinct transaction_id based on user_account and 24hrs time periods. An example is shown below.
data



user_account
transaction_date
transaction_id
cumulative_distinct_count




X0119989
2024-04-03 14:03:46
G0000006
1


X0119989
2024-04-22 22:35:16
G0000005
1


X0119989
2024-04-22 22:56:43
G0000004
2


X0119989
2024-04-25 20:24:36
G0000003
1


X0119989
2024-04-25 21:02:54
G0000002
2


X0119989
2024-04-25 21:52:13
G0000001
3


X0119999
2024-04-01 22:44:05
G0000012
1


X0119999
2024-04-01 22:46:00
G0000011
2


X0119999
2024-04-01 22:54:21
G0000010
3


X0119999
2024-04-01 22:59:33
G0000009
4


X0119999
2024-04-01 23:07:46
G0000008
5


X0119999
2024-04-02 00:02:20
G0000007
6



In the table above, the transaction id "G0000006" in the first row have 1 in columns "cumulative_distinct_count" is because there is no other transaction id except for itself happened over the past 24 hours of "2024/4/3 14:03:46".The transaction id "G0000004" in third row have 2 owing to the fact that over the past 24 hours of "2024/4/22 22:56:43" there are two transactions including "G0000004" and "G0000005" happened. What I'd like to do is to compute column "cumulative_distinct_count".
I'm currently find a undesired solution using apply method of pandas. The code is shown below.
def count_unique_id(x):
    condition = (data['datetime'].between(x['datetime'] - dt.timedelta(days=1), x['datetime'])) & (data['user_account'] == x['user_account'])
    return data[condition]['transaction_id'].nunique()


data['count_unique_id'] = data.swifter.apply(count_unique_id, axis=1)

The solution above took too much time for me due to large amount of data having over 3 million rows. I'm looking for other solutions which can run faster.
Thanks in advance.

There is no rolling.nunique so you would have to use a groupby.rolling.apply. Since rolling is only supported on numeric data, you can first factorize your IDs.
# ensure datetime
df['transaction_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['transaction_date'])

# we must sort
# by group since we'll later convert to array
# by transaction_date since rolling on datetime expected sorted timestamps
df.sort_values(by=['user_account', 'transaction_date'], inplace=True)

df['cumulative_distinct_count'] = (df
   .assign(num_id=lambda d: pd.factorize(d['transaction_id'])[0])
   .groupby('user_account', sort=False)
   .rolling('24h', on='transaction_date')['num_id']
   .apply(lambda x: x.nunique()).values
)

Output:
   user_account    transaction_date transaction_id  cumulative_distinct_count
0      X0119989 2024-04-03 14:03:46       G0000006                        1.0
1      X0119989 2024-04-22 22:35:16       G0000005                        1.0
2      X0119989 2024-04-22 22:56:43       G0000004                        2.0
3      X0119989 2024-04-25 20:24:36       G0000003                        1.0
4      X0119989 2024-04-25 21:02:54       G0000002                        2.0
5      X0119989 2024-04-25 21:52:13       G0000001                        3.0
6      X0119999 2024-04-01 22:44:05       G0000012                        1.0
7      X0119999 2024-04-01 22:46:00       G0000011                        2.0
8      X0119999 2024-04-01 22:54:21       G0000010                        3.0
9      X0119999 2024-04-01 22:59:33       G0000009                        4.0
10     X0119999 2024-04-01 23:07:46       G0000008                        5.0
11     X0119999 2024-04-02 00:02:20       G0000007                        6.0


Hi mozway, apologies for my late replying. The solution you provided works for me. It runs N times faster than my original solution. Thank you. I appreciate it.

One approach is the followwing:
import pandas as pd
from datetime import timedelta

data = {
    'user_account': ['user1', 'user1', 'user1', 'user2', 'user2', 'user2'],
    'transaction_id': ['G0000006', 'G0000005', 'G0000004', 'G0000010', 'G0000009', 'G0000008'],
    'transaction_date': [
        '2024/04/03 14:03:46', 
        '2024/04/03 18:20:00', 
        '2024/04/22 22:56:43', 
        '2024/04/22 14:03:46', 
        '2024/04/23 18:20:00', 
        '2024/04/24 22:56:43'
    ]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['transaction_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['transaction_date'])

df = df.sort_values(by=['user_account', 'transaction_date'])

def rolling_distinct_count(group):
    result = []
    for i in range(len(group)):
        start_time = group['transaction_date'].iloc[i] - timedelta(days=1)
        end_time = group['transaction_date'].iloc[i]
        count = group[(group['transaction_date'] > start_time) & (group['transaction_date'] <= end_time)]['transaction_id'].nunique()
        result.append(count)
    return pd.Series(result, index=group.index)

df['cumulative_distinct_count'] = df.groupby('user_account').apply(rolling_distinct_count).reset_index(level=0, drop=True)

print(df)

which gives

  user_account transaction_id    transaction_date  cumulative_distinct_count
0        user1       G0000006 2024-04-03 14:03:46                          1
1        user1       G0000005 2024-04-03 18:20:00                          2
2        user1       G0000004 2024-04-22 22:56:43                          1
3        user2       G0000010 2024-04-22 14:03:46                          1
4        user2       G0000009 2024-04-23 18:20:00                          1
5        user2       G0000008 2024-04-24 22:56:43                          1


Hi @Serge de Gosson de Varennes, it's really nice of you to give me a different idea about the problem I encountered. Maybe for loop doesn't really fit my large data. Cuz there are more than 500,000 groups in my data. Thank you for you time!

Use : from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer .It works efficiently for Huge datasets and very fast.
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer 

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'user': ['X0119989', 'X0119989', 'X0119989', 'X0119989', 'X0119989', 'X0119989', 
             'X0119999', 'X0119999', 'X0119999', 'X0119999', 'X0119999', 'X0119999'],
    'date': ['2024-04-03 14:03:46', '2024-04-22 22:35:16', '2024-04-22 22:56:43', 
             '2024-04-25 20:24:36', '2024-04-25 21:02:54', '2024-04-25 21:52:13',
             '2024-04-01 22:44:05', '2024-04-01 22:46:00', '2024-04-01 22:54:21',
             '2024-04-01 22:59:33', '2024-04-01 23:07:46', '2024-04-02 00:02:20'],
    'id': ['G0000006', 'G0000005', 'G0000004', 'G0000003', 'G0000002', 'G0000001',
           'G0000012', 'G0000011', 'G0000010', 'G0000009', 'G0000008', 'G0000007']
})

# Preprocessing
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])   
df.sort_values(by=['user', 'date'], inplace=True)

# Initialize MultiLabelBinarizer
mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()

def f(df):
 # Convert transaction IDs to binary representation
 binarized_id = mlb.fit_transform(df['id'].values[:,None])
 # Calculate the cumulative sum of unique IDs over time
 binarized_id_cumsum = binarized_id.cumsum(axis=0)
 # Calculate start times for the 24-hour windows
 start_times = df['date'].values - np.timedelta64(1,'D')
 # Find the indices where the 24-hour window starts
 start_idx = np.searchsorted(df['date'].values, start_times,side='left')
 #represents the cumulative sum of unique IDs up to the current point.
 current_cumsum =  binarized_id.cumsum(axis=0)
 #represents the cumulative sum of unique IDs up to the start of the window.
 previous_cumsum = np.vstack([np.zeros(binarized_id_cumsum.shape[1]),binarized_id_cumsum[:-1] ])

 new_ids_in_window = current_cumsum - previous_cumsum[start_idx]
 
 df['cumulative_distinct_count'] = (new_ids_in_window > 0).sum(axis=1)
 return df

# Apply the function and reset the index
df = df.groupby('user')[['date', 'id']].apply(f).reset_index(drop=True)
print(df)
'''
                  date        id  cumulative_distinct_count
0  2024-04-03 14:03:46  G0000006                          1
1  2024-04-22 22:35:16  G0000005                          1
2  2024-04-22 22:56:43  G0000004                          2
3  2024-04-25 20:24:36  G0000003                          1
4  2024-04-25 21:02:54  G0000002                          2
5  2024-04-25 21:52:13  G0000001                          3
6  2024-04-01 22:44:05  G0000012                          1
7  2024-04-01 22:46:00  G0000011                          2
8  2024-04-01 22:54:21  G0000010                          3
9  2024-04-01 22:59:33  G0000009                          4
10 2024-04-01 23:07:46  G0000008                          5
11 2024-04-02 00:02:20  G0000007                          6
'''

Explanation of previous_cumsum code using an example :
import numpy as np

# Imagine these are the cumulative counts of ice cream flavors
binarized_id_cumsum = np.array([[1, 0, 0],  # Day 1: Vanilla
                               [1, 1, 0],  # Day 2: Vanilla and Chocolate
                               [1, 1, 1]])  # Day 3: Vanilla, Chocolate, and Strawberry

print(binarized_id_cumsum)
# Create the previous cumulative sum
aa = np.zeros(binarized_id_cumsum.shape[1])
bb = binarized_id_cumsum[:-1]

previous_cumsum = np.vstack([aa,bb])
print(previous_cumsum)
'''
[[0. 0. 0.]
 [1. 0. 0.]
 [1. 1. 0.]]

'''
  

